# Why is the measure of a boundary of an open ball positive in only a countable number of cases?

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish (complete separable metric) space and $\mathbb{P}$ a Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of points dense in $X$. How can you prove that there is at most a denumerable number of values $r > 0$ where $\mathbb{P}(\partial B(x_i, r)) > 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

(Here $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of the set $A$ and $B(a, b)$ denotes an open ball with center $a$ and radius $b$.)

This assertion is taken for granted in Skorohod's paper "Limit theorems for stochastic processes" on p. 281. I would be very grateful if you could explain to me why it holds and apologies if it's meant to be obvious. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It is ambiguous at which point the quantifiers are. Is it "for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ there are at most countably many $r > 0$ [...]" or "there are at most countably many $r > 0$ so that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ [...]"?

Answer (score 2):

Note that (why?)

$$
\partial B_r (x)\subset \{y \mid d(x,y)=r\}. 
$$
(But in general, equality does not hold).

Hence, the sets $(\partial B_r (x))_{r>0}$ are pair wise disjoint.

Now it is easy to see that in a collection of pair wise disjoint measurable sets $(M_i)_i$ at most countably many can have positive measure. Otherwise, one of the sets
$$
\{i \mid \mu(M_i) \geq 1/n\} \text{ with } n \in \Bbb{N}
$$
would be infinite (even uncountable), which is impossible since $\mu$ is a finite measure, in your case even a probability measure.

This is sometimes called the **uncountable pigeon hole pinciple**.

Comment: @CameronBuie: whoopsy daisies, thanks! I fixed it.

Comment: The point is that there is some natural number $n$ (i don care which) for which the set is infinite. With "for a finite measure" I mean that $\mu$ is a finite measure, in your case even a probability measure.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Writing math on a mobile phone is hard :)

Comment: It is, indeed!${}$